# Laravel - Undefined variable: pipes

Tags: php, laravel

I when I press button to save registration I got error:

```
ErrorException in StreamBuffer.php line 295:
Undefined variable: pipes
```

The code before this error work fine, I don't change my code and now I got this error.

```
   protected function postRegister(RegisterRequest $request) {

    $this->user->name = $request->name;
    $this->user->email = $request->email;
    $this->user->password = bcrypt($request->password);


   Mail::send('request', array(
        'name' => $request->get('name'),
        'email' => $request->get('email'),
         'number' => $request->get('number'),
        'adrres' => $request->get('adrres')

    ), function ($message) {

    $message->from('no.replay@gmail.com', 'Report');

     $message->to('me@gmail.com')->subject('Report');

});
    return redirect('users/login');
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Show the code please.

Comment: I don't use variable pipes and I don't understend how show this error

Comment: It's `Mail` related issue. A lot of people have [similar problem](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/issues/490), maybe this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Change in `.env` file :-

**MAIL_DRIVER=smtp to MAIL_DRIVER=mail**